# I guess $G/N\cong G'/N'$ doesn't hold in this case, but I cannot prove that.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

I guess the following proposition is false.
But I cannot prove that the following proposition is false.

> Let $G$ be a group.
> Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.
> Let $G'$ be a group.
> Let $N'$ be a normal subgroup of $G'$.
> Suppose that $G\cong G'$.
> Suppose that $N\cong N'$.
> Then, $G/N\cong G'/N'$ holds.

Intuitively, I think the following proposition is true.

> Let $G$ be a group.
> Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.
> Let $G'$ be a group.
> Let $N'$ be a normal subgroup of $G'$.
> Suppose that $G\cong G'$ and $f$ is an isomorphism from $G$ to $G'$.
> Suppose that $N\cong N'$ and $f|_N$ is an isomorphism from $N$ to $N'$.
> Then, $G/N\cong G'/N'$ holds.

Comment: Let $G=G'=C_2\oplus C_4$ (where $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$, and $\oplus$ is the direct sum). Then $G$ has a subgroup $N$ isomorphic to $C_2$ with $G/N$ isomorphic to $C_4$, and it also has a subgroup $N'$, also isomorphic to $C_2$, with $G/N'$ isomorphic to $C_2\oplus C_2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the case $G = G' = \mathbb{Z}$.   Then $N = \langle 2 \rangle$ and $N' = \langle 3 \rangle$ are isomorphic since they're both infinite cyclic, but their quotients are not as they are $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$ respectively.

Your refined version is correct.  Define a map $f': G \to G'/N'$ by $f'(x)=f(x)N'$.  The kernel will be $N$ by your assumptions, and since this is surjective you're done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.